# Present perfect and present simple meaningfully

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the difference between these two sentences semantically?

1. The class is finished.
2. The class has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically in the first sentence finished is used as an adjective and in the second sentence finished is used as an intransitive verb

Semantically there is no difference between the above two sentences.

Comment: Is there any situation than can draw a distinction between them ? With adverbs or any other words.

Comment: Syntactically in the first sentence finished is used as an adjective and in the second sentence finished is used as an intransitive verb

Comment: I meant if I use yet and negative is this also true for both of them? The class has not finished yet, the class is not finished yet.

Comment: As far as I can think there is no distinction

Comment: @KshitijSingh are you ok with sentence 2?

Comment: Yes The play finished at 10:30